# Getting Failed to restart tlu.service: Interactive authentication required while executing a remote command in gcp vm

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

I am trying to restart a service on a linux vm non interactively using following command.

```
gcloud compute ssh {user}@{vm_name} --command="{script}" --project={tenant_project_name} --zone={vm_zone} --tunnel-through-iap --quiet
 script = systemctl restart tlu
```

I have seen many articles and came to conclusion to run `sudo su` initially and run the retart command. But when i ran `sudo su` the pipeline agent ran for a long time (till now). However if I try inside the vm, after executing `sudo su` password is not prompted.

Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

When running the '**`sudo su`**' command to connect the Linux VM from outside, it normally needs you manually provide the password of a valid user that can login to the VM.

Similarly, when you run this command in pipeline without interactive mode, the pipeline will keep waiting for you to provide the required password till gets time-out. To pass the password to the '**`sudo su`**' command, you can try using pipe like as below.

```bash
password="xxxx"
echo $password | sudo su
```

---

When you try on the Linux VM, because you have manually provided the correct username and password to login to the VM, when directly manually running the '**`sudo su`**' command on the VM, it generally will not ask you to provide the password again.

---